# New user problem

Tags: objects

We all learn differently - however I'm having a real problem - the examples I'm finding are unusable.  Why?  Because the person creating the example is a multi-year users who can Blend in their sleep, so the example is something like "Click here, click,click,dothis,dothis,dragthis(all at the speed of an expert user) When it should be "Step 1, do this (pause) so that I can follow along in my Blender step for step. Then (continue) Step 2 click on (pause) ...

Not here are the ingredients - go make the cake.

Comment: Check the channel tutor4u, the hammer tutorial was very helpful to me

Comment: There are also a lot of free beginner Blender tutorials on yt. You will find out after a few minutes whether the speed is ok for u. You are right - this forum is definitely not for bloody beginners or people who started learning Blender a week ago.

Comment: By the way: you are getting the downvotes because this „forum“ only accepts questions about Blender problems - not about this forum itself. These are the rules - I didn’t make them and I had lot of troubles with them too…and some are just ridiculous - of course that’s just my personal opinion

Comment: You always can pause a video with the pause button ;-) YT also allows you to reduce the speed to 0.25 if you want to watch something in slow motion.

Comment: There are many tutorials out there for different target audiences. Some for more advanced users, others for beginners. The quality is obviously varying since everyone can upload videos to YouTube, but you should be able to find good ones. For the very basics Blender provides a [playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLa1F2ddGya_-UvuAqHAksYnB0qL9yWDO6) on their own YouTube channel.  I can also recommend the tutorials and courses by Creative Shrimp (Gleb Alexandrov, Aidy Burrows and others). Their content ranges from beginners to advanced users.

Comment: Don't make the cake - make the donut! (trust me, we've all done it) - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nIoXOplUvAw

Answer (score 2):

Blender Stack Exchange is not meant to provide a beginner’s guide to blender. You are expected to have some previous knowledge. Where to get that foundational knowledge is up to you. A lot of users start with YouTube tutorials by Blender Guru and others. If you can’t find a suitable tutorial anywhere, I recommend you read the [Blender Manual](http://docs.blender.org/manual). That is where I learned the fundamentals. It’s not as right-out-the-gate as a tutorial: You have to learn some concepts such as jargon and UI principles first, but they discuss that in a chronological order.